# rails build associations from has_many through has_many raise error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a very special cases. I understand maybe db design is not very awesome, but I cannot change that.

```
class Employer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contract_employers
  has_many :contracts, through: :contract_employers
  has_many :crm_contacts, through: :contract_employers

# typical join table, with key: contract_id and employer_id
class ContractEmployer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contract
  belongs_to :employer
  has_many :crm_contacts

# CrmContact table has key: contract_employer_id
class CrmContact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contract_employer
  has_one :employer, through: :contract_employer
```

Given

```
employer = Employer.create
```

I have no issue to run

```
employer.contracts.create
```

However, if I try to run

```
employer.crm_contacts.create
```

It raise error

> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection: Cannot modify association 'Employer#crm_contacts' because the source reflection class 'CrmContact' is associated to 'ContractEmployer' via :has_many.

I checked the rails source code, basically it states very clearly

> ```
>     # Construct attributes for :through pointing to owner and associate. This is used by the
>     # methods which create and delete records on the association.
>     #
>     # We only support indirectly modifying through associations which have a belongs_to source.
>     # This is the "has_many :tags, through: :taggings" situation, where the join model
>     # typically has a belongs_to on both side. In other words, associations which could also
>     # be represented as has_and_belongs_to_many associations.
>     #
>     # We do not support creating/deleting records on the association where the source has
>     # some other type, because this opens up a whole can of worms, and in basically any
>     # situation it is more natural for the user to just create or modify their join records
>     # directly as required.
> ```

So only typical join table supports `model.associations.create`? Any suggestion for my user case?

Take my case for example, even rail is willing to do the job. How could `employer.crm_contacts.create` create middle table record `ContractEmployer`? Yes, it knows `employer.id`, but it has no clue what `contract.id` is, right?

Comment: Yes, your case is quite unconventional. I don't think you'll get any help from rails here. But you can always write a couple of helper methods, no?

Comment: I'm also curious, what led to this db design decision. First time I'm seeing something like this.

Comment: for a more than 10 years project, no one knows what happens previously :( Certainly, no one is daring to change now since too much logic already implemented based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails can not create middle table record in this case, but you can.

And I am completely agree with this (comments in rails source code `/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/through_association.rb`):

> in basically any situation it is more natural for the user to just
>   create or modify their join records directly as required

I don't see a problem here.

```
class Employer < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  def create_crm_contact
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      contract = contracts.create  # will create both `contract` and associated `contract_employer`

      # find the `contract_employer` that has been just created
      contract_employer = contract_employers.find_by(contract_id: contract.id)

      contract_employer.crm_contacts.create
    end
  end
```